# How do I pivot this source table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
Position      | EmpNumber | Name         | Status
1             | 1234      | Fred         | Active
2             | 1235      | Popeye       | Active
2             | 1236      | Olive        | Active
2             | 1237      | Scooby       | Active
2             | 1238      | Homer        | Active
3             | 1239      | Bart         | Active
3             | 1240      | Tom          | Active
4             | 1241      | Jerry        | Active
5             | 1242      | Bugs Bunny   | Active
```

I want to query that, and pivot it, so I only get the position (column 1) once and columns for each EmpNumber (column 2) aliased as Emp1, Emp2 etc. the worse case will ever be 4 numbers against each position. So my required results would be:

```
Position | Emp1       | Emp2  | Emp3   | Emp4
1        | Fred       | NULL  | NULL   | NULL
2        | Popeye     | Olive | Scooby | Homer
3        | Bart       | Tom   | NULL   | NULL
4        | Jerry      | NULL  | NULL   | NULL
5        | Bugs Bunny | NULL  | NULL   | NULL
```

I want all of the attributes for each row, maybe as single columns or maybe concatenated into a single field i.e. "1234,Fred,Active", but have just used the Name column above to keep it simple for now.

Also interested in how to make it dynamic just in case additional rows ever featured against the position.

Comment: Where do the column names `Emp1`, `Emp2` come from in the original table?

Comment: I think you just want `GROUP_CONCAT(Name)` and `GROUP BY Position`.

Comment: Was aliasing the new columns. 4 columns (worse case position 2 has 4 employees hence Emp1, Emp2, etc.

Comment: A pivot moves repeated data values into the column names. There's no `Emp1` value in the table.

Comment: In other words, why is Popeye in Emp1 column, not Emp2?

Comment: Because he’s the 1st employee of 4 in position 2. Popeye, Olive, Scooby then Homer

Comment: Ah, I don’t want the content as a column name

Comment: So where are the column names supposed to come from? Just sequential numbers up to the maximum number of repetitions? You'll need to use dynamic SQL to get the maximum count.

Comment: Do you have to do this in SQL? It will be much easier in a programming language.

Comment: Perhaps pivot was the wrong word then.  Popeye, Olive, scooby & Homer are all against Position 2.  I want to report 1 line for position 2 and transpose those 4 occupants wide instead of long

Comment: `SELECT position, GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY EmpNumber) AS names FROM table GROUP BY position`

Comment: Yep 1-4 just represented the number of occurrences on position 2. There would never be more than 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in a subquery to combine all the names from the same position into a comma-separated list, then use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` in the main query to extract them into separate columns.

```
SELECT position, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(names, ',', 1) AS Name1,
    IF(namecount > 1, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(names, ',', 2), ',', -1), NULL) AS Name2,
    IF(namecount > 2, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(names, ',', 3), ',', -1), NULL) AS Name3,
    IF(namecount > 3, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(names, ',', 4), ',', -1), NULL) AS Name4
FROM (
    SELECT position, GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY EmpNumber) AS names, COUNT(*) AS namecount
    FROM yourTable 
    GROUP BY position
) AS subquery
```